# System Information on 12.3 crashes Mathematica?

Tags: installation, version-12.3

After installing MMa 12.3 on Windows I did the following:

```
Help
About Mathematica
( Click on ) System Information
```

That crashed MMa.

I did the same on MMa 12.2 without problems.

Can anyone who uses MMa 12.3 on Windows confirm this? ( Or is it specific to my PC )

Comment: Did it really crash to Frontend or did it hang? I had a similar experience on MacOS but hanging instead of a crash.

Comment: Does it crash if you evaluate SystemInformation[]?

Comment: Yes, it crashed on SystemInformation[]. - @Philipp No hang, MMa disappeared. - Kernels still running though.

Comment: Stephen Wolfram was proud in his blog about this fast delivery of 12.3, but having worked in Software Quality Assurance that worried me. - Clearly SystemInformation[] was not tested ( on all platforms ). This is BAD.

Comment: Honestly, I really cannot understand why 12.3.0 was rushed out that way. There are a whole bunch of regressions which didn't get fixed before release. SW mentioned there will be a 12.3.1. Hopefully these issues get ironed out rather soon than late.

Comment: Almost work fine ,no crash (on Windows 10), but I can't enlarge the window .Strange...

Comment: @niloderoock: Works fine on my machine using Windows 10, x86, 64-bit with SystemInformation[].

Comment: @niloderoock, I've only heard of one crash in SystemInformation in 12.3.  And that was due to an OpenGL driver misreporting the supported version of GLSL.  If a driver update doesn't solve it, capture the crash dump via Task Manager and send it into Tech Support.

Comment: @Moo I have Windows 10 20H2 Build 19042.985. What version do you have? - My last Windows update is from 15/5-'21. Why would I need an OpenGL driver update? If I do need one, then Wolfram should recommend it.

Comment: I have Windows 10 20H2, and both `Help > System Information` and `SystemInformation[]` work for me.

Comment: Which Build of 10 20H2 do you have?

Comment: @niloderoock My build number is `19042.985`, with `Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.2020.0` also installed.

Comment: @niloderoock: I have MS Windows 10 Home, Version: 10.0.19041 Build 19041. I also updated my display driver as I tried running some new MMA 12.3 stuff and it was trying to access the GPU and was having issues.

Comment: Confirm it in 12.3 on Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: @user64494 Have you been able to fix this issue at all?

Comment: Similar sporadic failures - don't need to run the SystemInformation[] for this to happen. The Mathematica application just goes away when moving cursor to another application. But the kernels remained running. I just updated the display drivers from NVidia to see if that helps. Will update if i notice any change in behavior.  (The latest Windows update is causing a lot of issues so it may not be related to your issue.)

Comment: Thanks @xsk8rat, please keep us posted. ( I stopped using 12.3, I am on 12.2 now )

Comment: @nilo e rook The 12.3 application has been running stably since yesterday. I understand your reluctance, to use 12.3. I staying current in the hope that they will fix the DICOM image import they broke in 12.1. But all CT image processing has to be done in 12.0.

Comment: It's working for me in 12.3.1 today.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I'll get 12.3.1 asap.